# Incorrect size of div in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Goodnight everyone.
I'm having some trouble with combining a drag and drop script and Bootstrap

example can be seen here:
http://goedgevonden.net/laurent/index.html

As you can see, when you try to drag the eyes or mouth (in the left menu) a droparea colors yellow. This drop area is set to a width of 55% (showing correctly) and a height of 100% (only a small yellow bar shows up). Whats causing the shrinkage of my div in height? Anyone has a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Greetings,
Alfred Kwak.

Comment: Post a sample of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because that element and its parent don't really contain anything so the parent takes the height of a normal row, which in this case is 20px. Hence the element's 100% height makes it equal to the parent's height, which is 20px.

You will need to manually set either the element's or the parent's height to something specific (e.g. 100px).

Comment: That made sense. Thanks for the constructive answer!